# Can someone explain the [explanation] tag to me?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [explanation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/explanation) tag has 23 questions.  Some appear to ask for [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) or [meaning-in-context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context), and should probably just be replaced by those tags.

As for the other questions, I don't see what they have in common.

What should be done with this tag?

Comment: Something which might work is to make it a synonym of "meaning-in-context", which should re-tag all its instances. However, questions where that would be inappropriate would need to be dealt with first.

Answer (score 3):

I can't even explain why the tag exists at all, let alone what it might be supposed to mean.

I could hazard a guess that some people might feel that asking for an *explanation* of a preferred choice (as opposed to simply asking [Should I use “such that,” “so that,” or “in a way that”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204588/)) might make a question more "On Topic" (i.e. - less a "matter of opinion").

But quite frankly, it seems to me about as useful as the tag for **[usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage)** - I'd say get rid of both.

Comment: We need to get rid of meaning, too. Meaning-in-context might do.

Comment: [tag:usage] is a separate discussion. I think it means "Can you tell me whether a sizeable population of English speakers would actually say it this way?"

Answer (score 1):

It got worse, there are now 35 questions tagged [explanation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/explanation).

We should really stop this tag in its tracks now.